# I can't assign a input select value from a fetch with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

Basically I have a function onBlur that fetches some data, then I place the data into some fields that are being controlled with react-hook-form.
Everything but selects are being set, I don't know if there's something wrong with the libs, or it's just me not doing it right.
This would be the flow:
[image: GIF]

Filling up the CEP Field would return an object (1st is the object that returns,2nd is the object that should be set on the Form):
[image]

This is how the form data is set after the data fetch:

```
addressReset({
        cep: res.cep,
        bairro: res.bairro,
        localidade: res.localidade,
        address: res.logradouro,
        uf: res.uf,
      });
```

And this would be my controller component:

```
<Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <TextField
            {...field}
            disabled={disabled && true}
            select={select ? true : false}
            fullWidth={fullWidth ? true : false}
            autoComplete={name}
            type={type}
            label={label}
            error={Boolean(errors[name])}
            helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name].message : ""}
            variant="outlined"
            required={required ? true : false}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            InputLabelProps={InputLabelProps}
            InputProps={InputProps}
            size={size}
            onBlur={onBlur}
          >
            {children && children}
          </TextField>
        )}
      />
```

It takes some props, but more importantly it's name is `uf`, I don't see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

On a `Select` component you need to pass an object with keys `label` and `value`.

https://mui.com/api/select/

Comment: In this case, I'm using the TextField component, and I shouldn't need to pass the value since the react-hook-form controller is 'controlling' my component value, any ideas?

Comment: If you use the `select` option you still must pass through `options` as children, and you still may need to use the `value` and `label`.

Comment: select 
Render a Select element while passing the Input element to Select as input parameter. If this option is set you must pass the options of the select as children.